# How to convert 3D pose to the bvh?

Tags: bvh

I got 3d pose data from the video using an Openpose.
And I want to convert that to bvh format.
But I didn't understand bvh format exactly.
I don't know What Motion's angle means and how to convert 3D pose data to the bvh format.(3D pose) 1(`X1, Y1, Z1, ... , Xn, Yn, Zn`), 2(`X1, Y1, Z1, ... , Xn, Yn, Zn`),.. m(`X1, Y1, Z1, ... , Xn, Yn, Zn`)